# How to access resource files after the 'go' tool installed the executable?

Tags: go

Lets assume that running `go install -v importpath` builds an executable and installs it into `$GOPATH/bin/program`. The `go` tool is unable to install resource files. When I run the `program`, I would like it to access some resource files that are under `$GOPATH/src/importpath`.

What is the best way of accessing such resource files from the installed executable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question has been asked [multiple](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/0bNcjrmmO2E/discussion) [times](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/XksK4klJ0Dg/discussion) on the go-nuts mailing list. The `go` tool doesn't offer a direct way to distribute additional resources at the moment. However, there are two workarounds available:

- write a simple script (awk should be sufficient) to convert any file into a `.go` file which just contains a single string constant and embed the file directly into the binary. This approach is used by the [Camlistore](http://camlistore.org/) project for example ([camlistored/ui/fileembed.go](http://camlistore.org/code/?p=camlistore.git;a=blob;f=server/go/camlistored/ui/fileembed.go)). [go-bindata](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata) does similar things.
- go-tour and many other projects are currently using the [Import](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/go/build/#Import) function of the `go/build` package to search through all `src/` folders listed in `$GOPATH` and `$GOROOT` to find the correct path of the package sources. Example: http://code.google.com/p/go-tour/source/browse/gotour/local.go?r=996704f8ef9e63949b3bc4d94b613ec4a7b5d99a#53

Comment: The camlistored/ui/fileembed.go file is no longer available. Are there other working examples that could be quoted into the answer for preservation's sake?

Comment: Is there a 2019 version of this answer?

Answer (score 1):

go install is not designed to do what you want to do.

If you insist on using go install, you can embed the resources in the executable (byte arrays in source code).

Another option is to use a deploy script that runs go install and then copies the resources to a place known by your executable.

If you want your program to be installable by people other than you, you should use a packaging system that is standard on the os you're targeting (e.g. apt/rpm on Linux, an installer executable on Windows, .dmg file on Mac etc.)