# go - Instructions for installing from the ubuntu ppa

Tags: ubuntu, installation, environment-variables, go

I've installed golang-stable using the [Go Language ppa](https://launchpad.net/~gophers/+archive/go) for Ubuntu.

The [Official Installation Instructions](http://golang.org/doc/install#freebsd_linux) seem to ignore this option, and don't mention it at all.

My question is: does anyone know if anything else is needed after doing the `sudo apt-get` for this package? In particular, do I have to manually set any environment variables?

I'm asking because I've been able to "`go get`" [Go-SDL](https://github.com/0xe2-0x9a-0x9b/Go-SDL), but when I try to execute its test I get the following error:

```
$ ./test
panic: No such environment variable: GOPATH
```

This kind of confuses me. Shouldn't that variable be initialized already? Especially given that I have been able to compile and install a library.

Comment: Does http://golang.org/doc/code.html?h=GOPATH#tmp_13 help?

Comment: Not much. That page says: "GOPATH tells the go command (and other related tools) where to find and install the Go packages on your system". I have already installed packages on my system. How can that be, if GOPATH isn't already set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `go` command that you installed in `/usr/lib/go/bin/` internally contains a default path that is used if the environment variable `GOPATH` is missing. In case of the Ubuntu package this default path points to `/usr/lib/go`. Thus the installation directory for Go-SDL is somewhere in `/usr/lib/go/src`. Installing Go-SDL in this way requires root priviledges.

I recommend you setup `GOPATH` as described in http://golang.org/doc/code.html and reinstall Go-SDL. For example:

```
# Uninstall Go-SDL from /usr/lib/go
sudo go clean -i github.com/0xe2-0x9a-0x9b/Go-SDL/...

# Setup GOPATH
mkdir -p $HOME/go/src
export GOPATH=$HOME/go

# Install Go-SDL into $GOPATH
go get -v github.com/0xe2-0x9a-0x9b/Go-SDL/...
```

The `test` from `github.com/0xe2-0x9a-0x9b/Go-SDL` needs to know `GOPATH` to find some resource files (based on [How to access resource files after the 'go' tool installed the executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443418/how-to-access-resource-files-after-the-go-tool-installed-the-executable)).

Comment: I managed execute the test! I think the GOPATH should be preset to something by the ppa. But ok! I should mention that `go clean` didn't work though. I still had to hunt down the folders manually and `sudo rm` them. In any case, thanks for your help and patience!