# Go Template.ParseFiles and filepath.Join

Tags: go

I am trying to load an html file from a directory and I am getting the error "open templates: no such file or directory"

My directory structure is below

/Users/{username}/go/src/app
main.go

/Users/{username}/go/src/app/templates
mytemplate.html

The error is coming from the line below

```
template.Must(template.ParseFiles(filepath.Join("templates", "mytemplate.html")))
```

I am new to go and just trying to get a feel for the syntax.

EDIT 1

I am building the project using the "go build" command and executing it out of the "app" directory shown above.

$GOROOT = /usr/local/go
$GOPATH = /Users/{username}/go

I also updated the directory structure to integrate the $GOPATH

Comment: Where are you running your program from? See this for information about relative path in Go : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071286/how-can-i-open-files-using-relative-paths-in-go

Comment: The templates folder is actually under the app directory.  I updated the question to clear it up.

Comment: Are you using `go run` or `go install` for your executable?  Remember that `go install` puts the binary in `$GOPATH/bin` folder.

Comment: I was using go build I was able to put in the absolute path to the file which resolved the issue.  Then using filepath.Join() to vary the file name and folder name.  My issue seems to be the same as the question seen in the link from @HectorJ.

Answer (score 1):

Check the working directory that your program has at runtime with

```
dir, _ := os.Getwd()
fmt.Println(dir)
```

Then you can use that to get the right path for the templates

`template.Must(template.ParseFiles(filepath.Join(dir, "templates", "mytemplate.html")))`

For production use you could get the val of `dir` fro a config file or the environment,

ref : https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getwd

EDIT: When you run the program make sure you are in the correct directory using `cd` in your terminal

Comment: I tried this and it did not work.  The working directory returned "/Users/{username}/templates/mytemplate.html" and the actual location is "/Users/{username}/go/src/{projectname}/templates/mytemplate.html"

Comment: So as per the comments above your working directory is no correct, how are you running you program ?

Comment: Using "go build" then executing it out of the /Users/{username}/go/src/app directory.

Comment: copy your templates under that app directory

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
template.Must(template.New("mytemplate.html").ParseFiles("templates/mytemplate.html"))
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: I tried this, but I received the same error as the original posting.