# Get the parent path

Tags: go

I am creating Go command-line app and I need to generate some stuff in the current directory (the directory which the user execute the commands from)

to get the `pwd` I need to use

```
os.Getwd()
```

but this give me path like

```
/Users/s05333/go/src/appcmd
```

and I need path like this

```
/Users/s05333/go/src/
```

which option I've in this case?
Omit the last string after the `/` or there is better way in Go?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/17072096/1335793

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Take a look at the [`filepath` package](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/), particularly [`filepath.Dir`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Dir):

```
wd,err := os.Getwd()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
parent := filepath.Dir(wd)
```

Per the docs:

> Dir returns all but the last element of path, typically the path's directory.

Comment: Thanks its working I'll accept the answer in 5 min, can you explain why its working ? :) why dir remove the last path?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - it does that because that's its purpose. Read the linked documentation.

Comment: I was surprised to find that this doesn't work in cases where the base directory ends in a trailing slash. `filepath.Dir("/hello/world/")` returns `"hello/world"` rather than the expected `/hello"`. You have to trim trailing slashes before passing the string into `filepath.Dir()` ‍♂️. https://go.dev/play/p/634Yh2U16yQ

Answer (score 3):

Another option is the `path` package:

```
package main
import "path"

func main() {
   s := "/Users/s05333/go/src/appcmd"
   t := path.Dir(s)
   println(t == "/Users/s05333/go/src")
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/path#Dir

Comment: The docs specifically warn that the `path` package won't work for filepaths on all operating systems (namely Windows) because it only deals with forward slashes, and to use `path/filepath` instead for OS filesystems.