# ReadFile returns nil when attempting to read file

Tags: go

I am getting `nil` for `sampleFlags` in my debugger when attempting to read my file `test.json`. I am not sure if it is a path issue or where the reader pointer is. How FetchFlags is triggered is by a `handler` in `server.go` that ultimately calls `FetchFlags`.

flags.go

```golang
package flags

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

type Flag struct {
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    Category string `json:"category"`
    Label    string `json:"label"`
}

func FetchFlags() []Flag {
    sampleFlags, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("test.json")
    fmt.Printf("File contents: %s", sampleFlags)
    var Flags []Flag
    _ = json.Unmarshal(sampleFlags, &Flags)
    return Flags
}
```

Structure:

```
/server
  server.go
/package
  /flags
    flags.go
    test.json
  /pack_a
  /pack_b
```

Comment: `ioutil.ReadFile()` returns the err as 2nd return value. Check what the error returned. It should help you.

Comment: Never ignore errors.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to open file relative to package path. This is a bad design approach. For example depending on compilation method Go may place binaries in `$GOROOT/bin` directory. And there will not be the `test.json` file.

Use absolute path for your file or use approaches from [How can I open files relative to my GOPATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071286/how-can-i-open-files-relative-to-my-gopath).

Answer (score 1):

The path should be relatve to your main.go(or equivalent) file and not your package.
(Absolute path should work as well but I am not 100% sure about that)

If you think about it then you will realize that `package/flags` is directly or indirectly imported into your main file.
Your code compilation/execution isn't jumping to `package/flags`, instead that code is imported to your main file.

I would recommend you to use abosulte path or path relative to your main file.