# Handling Go Git repositories and its non-code resources

Tags: git, build, go, build-process

I'm new to Go and I'm struggling to find the best way to handle Git repositories.

At this moment I'm using the Go's official proposed directories structure, but I think it has many pitfalls.

It's something like

```
$GOPATH
  bin
    non-important-stuff
  pkg
    non-important-stuff
  src
    github.com
      username
        reponame
```

The case is that i have many non-code resources, like default settings files, html templates and images... but it seems a little weird to me place it in the "src/github.com/username/reponame" directory (because the first "src" part).

**What are the most common solutions to this problem?**

Another problem I'm facing now is that I don't know the most common "make" tools to build an entire project with external resources like default settings files or html (the "go build/install" commands only take care of source code files). How do you take care of relative paths when the executable is "installed"?

**Disclaimer:** I've read this thread: [How to access resource files after the 'go' tool installed the executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443418/how-to-access-resource-files-after-the-go-tool-installed-the-executable) , but I didn't see reliable solutions. My executable is a server, and it's not an option to embed the settings files and recompile every time I want to reconfigure the server (and its not an option to pass all the settings parameters via execution parameters, because the settings file is very complex).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about web development.

As you correctly noted, the directory structure is meant for the code, and the go tool suite only takes care of building binaries and putting them in a conventional place (`pkg` or `bin`).

What you want is a complete deployment procedure for a binary + resource files.

You should either roll your own deployment procedure, or use an existing framework.

A sketch of a homemade procedure :

- put all the resources under a specific directory in your project (e.g. `resources/`)
- use `git archive resources/` to bundle the files
- copy the files next to your executable
- choose a way to adjust the local parameters (db server, db name, etc..)
- choose a way to make to have your server reload the resources (restart your server / systematically re-read the resources / check modification dates / ... )

If you are looking for an existing web framework :

[**Revel**](http://robfig.github.io/revel/) is one option, which takes care of a good number of points, among which hot recompilation during development, and a [deployment procedure](http://robfig.github.io/revel/manual/deployment.html).